# Producer/Consumer: Should i write condition.release() for the consumer?

Tags: python, multithreading

While i was studying on an example that taken from https://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-threads-synchronization-locks-rlocks-semaphores-conditions-events-and-queues/ , i saw that if i put the `self.condition.release()` into a comment in Consumer class, the program still do the same as before. Is this part necessarry, should i write it?

Thanks in advance.

The codes are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import threading


class Producer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, condition, variables):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.condition = condition
        self.variables = variables

    def run(self):
        count = 1
        while count < 10:
            self.condition.acquire()
            print("condition was acquired by {}".format(self.name))
            self.variables.append(count)
            print("'{}' was appended to list by {}".format(count, self.name))
            self.condition.notify()
            print("condition was notified by {}".format(self.name))
            self.condition.release()
            print("condition was released by {}".format(self.name))
            count += 1
            time.sleep(0.5)


class Consumer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, condition, variables):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.condition = condition
        self.variables = variables

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.condition.acquire()
            print("condition was acquired by {}".format(self.name))
            while True:
                if self.variables:
                    number = self.variables.pop()
                    print("'{}', was popped from list by {}".format(number, self.name))
                    break
                print("condition is waited by {}".format(self.name))
                self.condition.wait()
            # The part that i talked about is the below.
            # Should i put it out of the comment?
            # self.condition.release()
            # print("condition was released by {}".format(self.name))


__condition__ = threading.Condition()
__variables__ = []
t1 = Producer(condition=__condition__, variables=__variables__)
t2 = Consumer(condition=__condition__, variables=__variables__)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that part is necessary. Otherwise when a consumer thread breaks out of the `while` loop it will continue to hold the lock, potentially causing a deadlock.

The reason your current code doesn't break is that you only have one consumer and the consumer never breaks out of the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.